# TableSorter disappears on ReRender

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a table that has tablesorter on it.  It works great.  When I re-render the pageblock section that it is in, the table is then reloaded WITHOUT tableSorter.  Something's up with my rerender.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

TableSorter Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadTablesort(){
$j = jQuery.noConflict();    
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("[id$=searchResults]").tablesorter({theme: 'green', headers: {0: {sorter: false},  17: {sorter: false},  20: {sorter: false} } });
         });
    }
loadTablesort();
</script>
```

Here is my command button in the pageblock section.

```
  <apex:pageblocksection title="List"  rendered="{!var.size >0 }" 
id="propTable" columns ="1" >

    <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Refresh"
 rerender="propTable, searchresults" oncomplete="loadTablesort();"/>

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!var.size >0}" id='propertyList'>

    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!wrapperList}" id="searchResults" var="c"
 border="1" styleclass="tablesorter">

<Table code...>
```

EDIT:  javanoob - I've tried following your instructions, but TableSorter doesn't load when the page is loaded at all now.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


$j(document).ready(function () {
    loadtable();
    uncheckParentCheckBox();

    }


function loadtable(){
    $j("[id$=searchResults]").tablesorter({theme: 'green', headers: {0: {sorter: false},  17: {sorter: false},  20: {sorter: false} } });
    $j("[id$=searchResultsclient]").tablesorter({theme: 'green', headers: {0: {sorter: false},  17: {sorter: false},  20: {sorter: false} } });
    $j("[id$=consultantListPM]").tablesorter({theme: 'green'  });
    $j("[id$=consultantListPP]").tablesorter({theme: 'green'   });
    $j("[id$=clientResultListTable]").tablesorter({theme: 'green'   });

    }

</script>
```

Comment: I would factor out a function to be called from both the ready and the oncomplete as I doubt the ready will fire for the partial page update.

Comment: Hey Keith - thanks for the response.  What do you mean by 'the ready'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..it will work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(document).ready(function () {
        sortTable();
        uncheckParentCheckBox();
    });

    function sortTable(){
        j$("[id$=theaddrs]").tablesorter();
    }
</script
```

and from the command button oncomplete method make the call to sort table function

```
<apex:commandButton name="fetchResults" action="{!updateAvailableList}" reRender="searchResults" status="searchStatus" oncomplete="sortTable(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Javanoob... I tried this, but now the TableSort doesn't load on pageload.  What am I doing wrong here? (See my edit for code)

Comment: `j$ = jQuery.noConflict();` Do you have this in your code? otherwise it does not know what is j$.

Comment: see my updated code..I used the same code for my custom product selection page and it is working fine.

Comment: Perfect - thank you!  That's what was missing.  I'm going to start doing some javascript codeAcademy classes to get me up to speed.  (or should I do Jquery?).  Thanks!!

Comment: @RC82 I am also like you :) Don't have much JS expertise. I think Javascript basics are enough.